# cacti graph memory usage on server

Tags: linux, memory, memory-usage, cacti

yesterday for the first time I have installed into my server cacti to view the performance of the memory of my server because sometimes go down.
I have make an image of the memory usage graph. Can someone help me to understand or to view some problem? Thanks
I want to know if there is a problem of memory
the problem is that I have a server linux with 2 cpu, int he night I make a big import into the database and sometimes the apache service is stopped during the import, I thought that the problem is the memory, the graph is refer to tonight when I have started the import about at 21:30

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not answer such a question without getting more details. First of all, do you experience any performance related issues using your server? We don't know how much memory your server has and we don't know how many processes are executing and so many other details.

I can see that your server is swapping which is generally not a good indication. To keep your server optimum, you need to avoid swapping as much as you can. This can be done by estimating the needed memory by your applications and upgrade memory when needed.

Comment: the problem is that I have a server linux with 2 cpu, int he night I make a big import into the database and sometimes the apache service is stopped during the import, I thought that the problem is the memory, the graph is refer to tonight when I have started the import about at 21:30